# Getting an error when trying to insert data to a sql server table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am trying to insert data to a staging table using the following method:

```
public void InsertPayloadtoStaging(List<CustomPayload> payLoads, int batchId)
{
    try
    {
        string agentName = appSettings.AgentName;
        var tableName = string.Empty;

        DataTable payLoadData = new DataTable();
        DataColumn idcolumn = new DataColumn("Id", typeof(string));
        payLoadData.Columns.Add(idcolumn);

        DataColumn payLoadcolumn = new DataColumn("Payload", typeof(string));
        payLoadData.Columns.Add(payLoadcolumn);

        DataColumn scheduleIdcolumn = new DataColumn("BatchId", typeof(int));
        payLoadData.Columns.Add(scheduleIdcolumn);

        foreach (AgentPayload payLoad in payLoads)
        {
            DataRow dr = payLoadData.NewRow();

            dr["Id"] = payLoad.Id;
            dr["Payload"] = payLoad.Payload;
            dr["BatchId"] = batchId;

            payLoadData.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        switch (agentName)
        {
            case Constants.Agent1:
                tableName = _configuration.appSettings.Agent1_StagingTable;
                break;
            case Constants.Agent2:
                tableName = _configuration.appSettings.Agent2_StagingTable;
                break;
            case Constants.Agent3:
                tableName = _configuration.appSettings.Agent3_StagingTable;
                break;
            case Constants.Agent4:
                tableName = _configuration.appSettings.Agent4_StagingTable;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        this._connection.Open();

        using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(this._connection))
        {
            s.DestinationTableName = tableName;
            s.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
            s.BatchSize = _configuration.appSettings.AgentPayloadBatchSize;

            foreach (var column in payLoadData.Columns)
                s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());

            DataTableReader reader = payLoadData.CreateDataReader();

            s.WriteToServer(reader);
        }

        this._connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The the List contains an Id followed by a JSON string.

I am calling this method as follows:

```
InsertPayloadtoStaging(agentPayLoads, _batchId);
```

After I call the method, I am getting the following error:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: DestinationTableName

I am not sure as to why I am getting this error as I am passing the parameters as expected. I even unit tested the code and it was working fine. It is giving this error only when I am invoking this from another method.

Comment: Possible tableName to be null?

Comment: @DanielB the tableName is getting a value. The case 3 in the switch statement is true

Comment: Do you have a table with that table name and does it have those columns?

Comment: See msdn.  It looks like you need to do some additional initializations : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nikhilsi/2008/06/11/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-c-app/#respond

Comment: _"It is giving this error only when I am invoking this from another method."_ - so it works in other circumstances?

Comment: @CodingYoshi yes the table exists and the columns names are also matching

Comment: @stuartd yes it is working when I unit test it. But I am unable to call it from another method

Comment: Place a breakpoint into `this._connection.Open();` and watch the content of the `tableName`. Maybe a misspelling error into a table name ?

Comment: Also, verify that your connection is pointing to the expected server/database...

Comment: @user1429080 verified and it's correct

Comment: Check the relevant appSettings in the version where you get the error. Did you include the right settings for the agent and the various tableName values in the settings file? Since you mention it works in one scenario but not another, then that kind of difference would seem to be the most likely problem.

Comment: @ADyson the appSettings are up to date in all aspects

Comment: @Harry Can you tell us what, in fact, gets set as `tableName`? Partial quote from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.destinationtablename?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlBulkCopy_DestinationTableName): **However, if the table name uses an underscore ("_") or any other special characters, you must escape the name using surrounding brackets as in ([<database>.<owningschema>.<name_01>])**. Could this be an issue in your case?

Comment: @Harry well then you need to set some breakpoints and check what the values being set in the query actually are, because clearly it's not setting a valid table name. If you can observe that things seem to be set correctly, but it's still not working, then you need to verify your observations by stepping through the code. We cannot do that for you. Since you state that the code works in some circumstances, the code itself is unlikely to be the issue, it will be the settings, the data, or something else related in the environment. We can't see any of that, so it's hard to help much.

Comment: I suggest you start debugging your code and going through it line by line using the debugger. I doubt anyone can help you here so you may be wasting your time. Sounds like only you can figure out the issue because you have all the code.

Comment: @user1429080 yes the table name has an underscore. the name is stg.work_agent

Comment: @CodingYoshi I am unable to debug as the method I am calling is in a different solution within the project

Comment: Did you already try this as `tableName`: `[stg].[work_agent]`. Did it work?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *method I am calling is in a different solution within the project*? Normally projects are within a solution not the other way around. Please explain. Perhaps the question you should be asking is: *How do I debug when...?*